# HTML email - single td full width too short

Tags: html, email

When testing this email in Outlook (before double clicking to open the email in full), there is what looks like a blank/missing td at the end of the unsubscribe text at the bottom. The TD there should fill 100%. I tried with colspan="2" and 3 too but still the same result.

On browser like always it looks fine. Any obvious signs?

Screenshot Preview:
[image]

Code in JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6jp7xudd/ (although as mentioned, in the browser it looks fine. Only when you see the preview of it in outlook will this happen.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Demystifying Email Design</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <style>
    h3 { font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 30px; color: #ffffff; }
    td { color: #ffffff; font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; }
    a { text-decoration: none; color: #00a950; }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" bgcolor="#004964"  style="border:none;">
 <tr>
    <td height="456" vertical-align="top" valign="top">
     <img src="http://www.example.co.uk/example/14-12-14/main-img.jpg" alt="Merry Christmas from Wyles Hardy" width="800" height="454" style="display: block;" />
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td bgcolor="#004964" style="border:#004964;">
   <img src="http://www.example.co.uk/example/14-12-14/hr.jpg" alt="Merry Christmas from Wyles Hardy" width="800" height="15" style="display: block;" />
  </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
    <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" bgcolor="#004964"  style="border:none;">
     <tr>
        <td width="306" style="padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">
            <img src="http://www.example.co.uk/example/14-12-14/logo.jpg" alt="Wyles Hardy Logo" />
        </td>
        <td width="247">
            Wyles Hardy &amp; Co Ltd,<br>Ley hill Road, Bovingdon,<br>Hemel Hempstead<br>Hertfordshire,HP3 0NW
        </td>
        <td width="247">
            <br>
            <a href="" style="text-decoration:none;border:none;color:#ffffff;">Tel +44(0)1442 832234</a><br><a href="" style="text-decoration:none;border:none;color:#ffffff;">Fax +44(0)1442 834342</a><br><a href="mailto:enquiries@example.com" style="color:#00a950;">enquiries@example.com</a>
        </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" bgcolor="#004964" style="border:none;">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#004964" style="border:#004964;">
        <img src="http://www.example.co.uk/example/14-12-14/hr.jpg" alt="Merry Christmas from Wyles Hardy" width="800" height="15" style="display: block;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" bgcolor="#004964" style="border:none;">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px; padding: 5px 0 5px 0;" colspan="2">To unsubscribe from our mailing list or not to receive further emails from us, <unsubscribe><span style="color:#00a950;">click here</span></unsubscribe></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That `colspan="2"` on your last table cell might have something to do with it. Try getting rid of that (since there is no need for it).

Comment: Same issue with and without it unfortunately.

Comment: What happens if you add a `<br />` after your `</table>` tag? Does the block still appear?

Answer (score 0):

It definitely won't be a colspan issue in your case because you are separating by Tables, rather than rows. So in your case, the cells in each table have no correspondence with cells in any other table.

I can't actually replicate your issue. Either on my own Outlook, or in my Email on Acid test account.
I would however suggest adding a wrapper table that spans 100%, and then adding an align="center" to the cell of that wrapper table.
Then remove the alignment from the inner Tables. The Tables will inherit the cells centering, and your email will play nicer with this structure...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Demystifying Email Design</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <style>
    h3 { font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 30px; color: #ffffff; }
    td { color: #ffffff; font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; }
    a { text-decoration: none; color: #00a950; }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border:none;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" bgcolor="#004964" style="border:none;">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="456" vertical-align="top" valign="top">
                         <img src="http://www.example.co.uk/example/14-12-14/main-img.jpg" alt="Merry Christmas from Wyles Hardy" width="800" height="454" style="display: block;" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004964" style="border:#004964;">
                        <img src="http://www.example.co.uk/example/14-12-14/hr.jpg" alt="Merry Christmas from Wyles Hardy" width="800" height="15" style="display: block;" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" bgcolor="#004964"  style="border:none;">
                 <tr>
                    <td width="306" style="padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">
                        <img src="http://www.example.co.uk/example/14-12-14/logo.jpg" alt="Wyles Hardy Logo" />
                    </td>
                    <td width="247">
                        Wyles Hardy &amp; Co Ltd,<br>Ley hill Road, Bovingdon,<br>Hemel Hempstead<br>Hertfordshire,HP3 0NW
                    </td>
                    <td width="247">
                        <br>
                        <a href="" style="text-decoration:none;border:none;color:#ffffff;">Tel +44(0)1442 832234</a><br><a href="" style="text-decoration:none;border:none;color:#ffffff;">Fax +44(0)1442 834342</a><br><a href="mailto:enquiries@example.com" style="color:#00a950;">enquiries@example.com</a>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                </table>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" bgcolor="#004964" style="border:none;">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#004964" style="border:#004964;">
                    <img src="http://www.example.co.uk/example/14-12-14/hr.jpg" alt="Merry Christmas from Wyles Hardy" width="800" height="15" style="display: block;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" bgcolor="#004964" style="border:none;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px; padding: 5px 0 5px 0;">To unsubscribe from our mailing list or not to receive further emails from us, <unsubscribe><span style="color:#00a950;">click here</span></unsubscribe></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's it like without the span tag as this seems to be individual to this table. My last suggestion would be to add a width to body as it contains the tables. Can't see off the cuff why it is failing

Comment: I don't see any need to add a width to the body. I have never done that, and I build emails everyday.

Comment: I would usually have another table inside of my wrapper with the width I want, and then the tables inside of that with width set to 100%, or the same width as the table they're wrapped in

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my issue.

The 2 horizontal lines were both in a table tag above the issue area. So I moved the last horizontal line inside of the table where I was having my issue, so this table now is forced too 100% because of the size of the horizontal line image (which is 800px).

So this is now my last **table** tag.

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" bgcolor="#004964" style="border:none;">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#004964" style="border:#004964;">
        <img src="http://www.mangemails.co.uk/wyleshardy/14-12-14/hr.jpg" alt="Merry Christmas from Wyles Hardy" width="800" height="15" style="display: block;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px; padding: 5px 0 5px 0;">To unsubscribe from our mailing list or not to receive further emails from us, <unsubscribe><span style="color:#00a950;">click here</span></unsubscribe></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```